# RxJava / Retrofit API Call for every item in a list of unknown size

Tags: android, api, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm currently trying to use RxJava with Retrofit for the first time but can't seem to get anything working for my specific use case:

I begin by calling an API using retrofit to show cinemas near a users location.
I then use the cinema id which the user clicks on to display showtimes for this cinema i.e...

```
public interface ListingApiService
{
    @GET("/get/times/cinema/{id}")
    Call<ListingResponse> getShowtimes (@Path("id") String id);
}


Then using the interface....


public void connectAndGetApiData(String id)
    {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        ListingApiService listingApiService = retrofit.create(ListingApiService.class);

        Call<ListingResponse> call = listingApiService.getShowtimes(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListingResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ListingResponse> call, Response<ListingResponse> response)
            {
                List<Listing> listings = response.body().getListings()
                getAndDisplayImage(listings.get(0).getTitle());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListingAdapter(listings,R.layout.list_item_listing,getApplicationContext()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ListingResponse> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Log.e(TAG,t.toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

I then want to call a different API (contextual web search) to display an image of a relevant movie poster (just for a nice visual effect) for each movie listing. I know how to call the API for a single image, but I don't know how to make multiple calls. I've tried using RxJava code found elsewhere on the internet but none of it seems to work as I don't have prior knowledge of how many calls I will be making or what the search term will be. The code i'm using for a single call is:

```
public interface ListingImageApiService
{
    //https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.mashape.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?count=1&autoCorrect=false&q=Donald+Trump
    @Headers("X-Mashape-Key: apikey")
    @GET("/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?count=5&autoCorrect=false")
    Call<ListingImageResponse> getListingImages (@Query("q") String term);
}


 public void getAndDisplayImage(String search)
    {
        if (retrofit2 == null)
        {
            retrofit2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL2)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

    search = search + " poster";
    ListingImageApiService listingImageApiService = retrofit2.create(ListingImageApiService.class);


    Call<ListingImageResponse> call = listingImageApiService.getListingImages(search);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListingImageResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListingImageResponse> call, Response<ListingImageResponse> response)
        {
            System.out.println(response.body().toString());
            ListingImage a = new ListingImage();
            List<ListingImage> listingImages = response.body().getListingImage();
            System.out.println(listingImages.get(0).getUrl());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ListingImageResponse> call, Throwable t) 
        {

        }
    });
}
```

My question is, how would I use RxJava to make multiple calls using data for the list of movie titles of unknown size (which I can pass to getAndDisplayImage instead of a single string)? I have made several attempts but none seem to work for my use case. Thank you.

Comment: did you use `map` operator from `RxJava`?get data from first api and transform results to a new `observer` using operator and request for image .

Comment: Hi, I have looked into the map operator but I don't see how it solves my problem. I don't know how to make the API call for multiple objects. How could map do that? Does it not simply apply a function to a collection, or have I misunderstood the purpose of map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design should solve your problem.

This interface contains the endpoints used in the application.

```
public interface ListingApiService
{
    @GET("/get/times/cinema/{id}")
    Observable<List<MovieResponse>> getShowtimes (@Path("id") String id);

    @Headers("X-Mashape-Key: apikey")
    @GET("/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?count=5&autoCorrect=false")
    Observable<ListingImageResponse> getListingImages (@Query("q") String term);
}
```

Method which provides the retrofit object to make the call

```
private API getAPI() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("<your API endpoint address")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(API.class);
}
```

Make the call to get the `List<MovieResponse>`. This method also converts the `List` into a individual observable `MovieResponse` object.

```
private void getMovieListingsWithImages() {
    Observer<MovieResponse> observer = new Observer<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(MovieResponse movieResponse) {
            //for each movie response make a call to the API which provides the image for the movie
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error getting image for the movie", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished getting images for all the movies in the stream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    getAPI().getShowtimes()
            .flatMapIterable(movieResponseList -> movieResponseList) // converts your list of movieResponse into and observable which emits one movieResponse object at a time.
            .flatMap(this::getObservableFromString) // method converts the each movie response object into an observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
}
```

method which converts the `MovieResponse` object into an `Observable`.

```
private Observable<MovieResponse> getObservableFromString(MovieResponse movieResponse) {
    return Observable.just(movieResponse);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time and effort in replying. As a result, I have implemented something similar to how you propose doing it here, where I use type Listing and flatmap them to create an observable listing object which repeats onNext until finished. This really gave me the push I needed to implement RxJava, thanks again